# Powershell Question: How to check if password is implemented clarifications

Tags: powershell, shell, active-directory

So I tried messing around the basics by creating a bulk user script. I made 3 dummy accounts with different information.

I also set a securestring password for the accounts, but here's the thing, how do I check if I DID actually implement the passwords? Currently in my Active Directory, the users are created with a black arrow marked on the icon.

From what I understand its either I haven't enable the account or I didn't set a password for it. Is there a way for me to login into these dummy account to test if I have actually added the password?

Sorry, I'm a total beginner to this, still learning hence I have certain doubts. Im using a VM Win Server 2019 for practice.

Comment: Have you tried [runas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v%3Dws.11))?

Answer (score 0):

I check passwords are actual this way:

```
$de = New-Object -TypeName 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry' -ArgumentList @($null, 'UserName', 'Pa$$w0Rd')
if ($de.DistinguishedName -eq $null)
{
# Could not login to DC#
}
```

But user needs to be enabled and allowed to logon.